# Alamofire is getting slow on HTTPS but fine in HTTP

Tags: ios, swift, api, server, alamofire

In my App multiple Apis . i have 2 differnet server one is for HTTP and one for HTTPS 
When i Run my App on Http : it works fine 1st time for each Api and 2 second time for each Api same response time . 
But when i run App on https : for each APi first time taking extra time for each Api , then if i hit same Api again it is fast . Problem is why for first time for each APi is slow or taking extra time . But thing is not happened with Android App .

here is My Request builder Class : URLRequestBuilder.swift

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

protocol URLRequestBuilder: URLRequestConvertible, APIRequestHandler {

    var mainURL: URL { get }
    var requestURL: URL { get }
    var path: String { get  }
    var parameters: Parameters? { get }
    var method: HTTPMethod { get }
    var encoding: ParameterEncoding { get }
    var urlRequest: URLRequest { get }
}

extension URLRequestBuilder {

    var encoding: ParameterEncoding {
        switch method {
        case .get:
            return URLEncoding.default

        default:
            return JSONEncoding.default
        }
    }

    var mainURL: URL  {
        return URL(string: SERVER_URL)!
    }

    var requestURL: URL {
        var fullURL  = mainURL.absoluteString + path

        if L102Language.currentAppleLanguage() == "ar" && path.contains("?") {
            fullURL = fullURL + "&blLocaleCode=ar"
        } else  if L102Language.currentAppleLanguage() == "ar" {
            fullURL = fullURL + "?blLocaleCode=ar"
        }
        let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: fullURL)!
        return urlComponents.url!
    }

    var urlRequest: URLRequest {
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        request.httpMethod = method.rawValue

        if UserDefaults.standard.isUserLoggedIn()  {
            request.setValue(UserDefaults.standard.getAccessToken(), forHTTPHeaderField:  NETWORK_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        }
        request.setValue(NETWORK_REQUEST_TYPE, forHTTPHeaderField:  NETWORK_ACCEPT)
        request.setValue(NETWORK_REQUEST_TYPE, forHTTPHeaderField:  NETWORK_CONTENT_TYPE)
        //request.cachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy
        return request
    }

    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        return try encoding.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
    }
}


final class NetworkClient {

    let evaluators = [
        "somehttpsURL.com": ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
            certificates:  [Certificates.stackExchange],
            validateCertificateChain: true,
            validateHost: true)
    ]
    let session: SessionManager

    // 2
    private init() {

        session = SessionManager(
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: evaluators))
    }

    // MARK: - Static Definitions

    private static let shared = NetworkClient()

    static func request(_ convertible: URLRequestConvertible) -> DataRequest {
        return shared.session.request(convertible)
    }
}

struct Certificates {
    static let stackExchange =
    Certificates.certificate(filename: "certificate") 

    private static func certificate(filename: String) -> SecCertificate {
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "der")!
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
        let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, data! as CFData)!
        return certificate
    }
}
```

And my Request Handler Class is :

```
extension APIRequestHandler where Self : URLRequestBuilder {
   // For Response Object
   func send<T: AnyObject>(modelType: T.Type,  data: [UIImage]? = nil, success: @escaping ( _ servicResponse: AnyObject) -> Void, fail: @escaping ( _ error: NSError) -> Void, showHUD: Bool)  where T: Mappable {
        if let data = data {
            uploadToServerWith(modelType: modelType, images: data, request: self, parameters: self.parameters, success: success, fail: fail)
        } else {
            //print(requestURL.absoluteString)
            // NetworkClient.
          request(self).authenticate(user: APIAuthencationUserName, password: APIAuthencationPassword).validate().responseObject { (response: DataResponse<T>) in
               switch response.result {
               case .success(let objectData):
                  success(objectData)
                  break
               case .failure(let error):
                  print(error.localizedDescription)
                  if error.localizedDescription == RefreshTokenFailed {
                      self.getAccessTokenAPI(completion: { (value) in
                          if value == TOKEN_SAVED {
                               self.send(modelType: modelType, success: success, fail: fail, showHUD: showHUD)
                              return
                          }else {
                              fail(error as NSError)
                          }
                      })
                  } else {
                      fail(error as NSError)
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: It must be because you https will be a live server where there will be actual load on the server and http is at local where load is zero and api response is also cached which makes it fast the second time.

Comment: That behavior i already explained, i understand that. , it is not happening with other ios apps working on https and also not happened with Android App. That i want to know what is wrong on the server or Alamofire side in my code. Now you got my point. this behavior is bad for users' experience. becuase we want that IOS App works smooth every time for each request. And it is not happen in Android .

Comment: @Swati please check the above comment and might be your more comment will be helpfull for figure out the solution.

Comment: I must say that this not an issue of Alamofire 
One of these can be reason due to which it https is slow please check on all of these and act appropriately to either resolve or accept the delay: 
1: your https server have some redirect added to it due to which it is taking more time
2: your hosting is serving to may services, which causing more context switching or memory is near full, response is late
3: Your server's SSL certificate have some issue, try replace with some new valid certificate and check, 
or still you can check with other things, I am sure it is not because of Alamofire

Comment: @SulmanMalik if above 3 or any one of them are issues, then we can resolved on server side or some setting on IOS Side . becuase we are not facing such issue on Android App .

Comment: @SulmanMalik if above 3 points are there still Android App not facing first time slow for each Api